# Merge two onLoad scripts into one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onload

I have two onLoad scripts

```
<body  onload=" (function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= ($('body').height() - $(window).height()) ) {
                    $(window).scrollTop(1);
                }
                else if ( $(window).scrollTop() == 0 ) {
                    $(window).scrollTop($('body').height() - $(window).height() -1);
                }    
            });
        }); 
})( jQuery );">
```

and

```
<body onLoad="window.scroll(0, 1500)">
```

I need them in the same onLoad="" and still be working. Anyone who can help me with this? Thank you!!

Comment: You can put multiple statements, separated with `;`.

Comment: So 

<body  onload=" (function($){
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $(window).scroll(function() {
                if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= ($('body').height() - $(window).height()) ) {
                    $(window).scrollTop(1);
                }
                else if ( $(window).scrollTop() == 0 ) {
                    $(window).scrollTop($('body').height() - $(window).height() -1);
                }    
            });
        }); 
})( jQuery ); window.scroll(0, 1500);"> ?

Comment: I would suggest you to write your logic inside `<script>`

Comment: Wow that was simple, thank you!

Comment: Thanks Rayon, but the script doesn't work then.

Comment: The source code of that link scares. You should visit https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Answer (score 0):

```
<body  onload="

            $(window).scroll(function() 
            {
                if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= ($('body').height() - $(window).height()) ) 
                    $(window).scrollTop(1);

                else if ( $(window).scrollTop() == 0 ) 
                    $(window).scrollTop($('body').height() - $(window).height() -1); 
            });

">
```

Answer (score 0):

You're over complicating things a bit.

place a script tag at the bottom of your body tag, then put the code in there.

```
<body>
    .... OTHER HTML GOES HERE ....

    <script>
        (function($){ // you only need this if you have something jQuery conflicts with
            $(function(){
                $(window).scroll(function() {
                    if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= ($('body').height() - $(window).height()) ) {
                        $(window).scrollTop(1);
                    } else if ( $(window).scrollTop() == 0 ) {
                        $(window).scrollTop($('body').height() - $(window).height() -1);
                   }    
                });

                // your second onload thing
                window.scroll(0, 1500)
            }); 
         })( jQuery );
    </script>

</body>
```